# Shopify Shipping Script Discount on Customer Tag

Tags: ruby, shopify

I have a Shopify Plus account in which I am attempting to add a new condition to my Shipping Script that controls what shipping methods are displayed to customers. Specifically, I want to give customers with a specific tag access to free shipping. To control that

```
def freeItUp
  index = -1 
  if Input.cart.customer != nil and Input.cart.customer.tags != nil 
    Input.cart.customer.tags.index do |tag|
      return tag.upcase == "ALWAYSFREE"
    end 
  end
  return index > -1
end 

shippingMethodToDelete = (condition1 or condition2 or freeItUp) ? "UPS" : "FREE"

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
  puts shipping_rate.name
  shipping_rate.name.upcase.start_with?(shippingMethodToDelete)
end
```

However, I keep getting the following error

> fiber required for enumerator (Your Cart)
>
> fiber required for enumerator (Empty Cart)

I'm not terribly familiar with Ruby, but I'm using the same code block (above) in Line Item scripts with no issues. According to the [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/shopify-scripts#general-methods) I believe I'm not trying to access properties that don't exist. Any thoughts/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
  def always_free_tag?
    return false if Input.cart.customer.nil? || Input.cart.customer.tags.empty?
    Input.cart.customer.tags.any? do |tag|
      tag.upcase == "ALWAYSFREE"
    end
  end

  shippingMethodToDelete = (condition1 or condition2 or always_free_tag?) ? "UPS" : "FREE"

  Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
    puts shipping_rate.name
    shipping_rate.name.upcase.start_with?(shippingMethodToDelete)
  end
```

Also, can you share more of the stack trace and what line it points to?

Edit:  Great!  Glad that worked.  I think your issue is you were using `Array#index` which yields an index (integer) to the block (this line: `Input.cart.customer.tags.index`).  You're then calling `#upcase` on Numeric which isn't a method.  If you instead did this it would work as expected:

```
Input.cart.customer.tags.index do |i|
  return true if Input.cart.customer.tags[i].upcase == "ALWAYSFREE"
end
```

The other issue is that in ruby only `nil` and `false` are falsy in ruby, so your condition in `shippingMethodToDelete` likely wasn't returning the correct value.  Instead, I changed it so it always returns a boolean that way we can be sure `ALWAYSFREE` is searched for and evaluated correctly.  I think you were really close but take a look at [Enumerable#any](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for more examples.

Comment: the error was on the fourth line of code and the only errors available to me were the 'fiber' related ones, no stack trace. Your solution seems to work. 

Can you give me the rundown on what your solution fixed so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Hard to know exactly what was wrong but those stacktraces were not helpful clearly!  I added some more info, let me know if that answers your questions.

Comment: @MarkCooper I found the other issue that I forgot to explain as well.

Comment: That explains it. I'm not terribly down on Ruby, so that helps a lot.